# How do I stop my jquery draggable clone from moving far away from my mouse pointer?

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I'm working on a project where I'm creating a planning for the company I work for, where the planning is build by placing tables in a main table, and where every day of every week (which are all table rows) must be draggable into a table of the next week. an example of what I mean with the tables in a table is provided below:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Week 1</th>
        <th>Week 2</th>
        <th>Week n</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>user name</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>user function</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table inside-table week1>
            <tbody>
              <tr week1 index=Monday>
                <td>Monday</td>
                <td>Monday task</td>
                <td>Monday task hours</td>
              </tr>
              <tr week1 index=Tuesday>
                <td>Tuesday</td>
                <td>Tuesday task</td>
                <td>Tuesday task hours</td>
              </tr>
              etc.
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table inside-table week2>
            <tbody>
              <tr week2 index=Monday>
                <td>Monday</td>
                <td>Monday task</td>
                <td>Monday task hours</td>
              </tr>
              <tr week2 index=Tuesday>
                <td>Tuesday</td>
                <td>Tuesday task</td>
                <td>Tuesday task hours</td>
              </tr>
              etc.
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Every  with a week-number is a draggable, and every inside-table is a droppable.

No my problem: 
When I move my draggable, the clone is not positioned at the cursor, but it can be moved x amount of pixels in every direction possible, even out of sight for the user.

I've tried to use the cursorAt option for the Draggable Widget by jQuery, but that does nothing. I've also tried to use the appendTo with 'tbody', 'tr[index]' and 'parent', where the first two make the  show everywhere in the table which is not what I want (although the helper did stay in the right place), and the last one did nothing.

My draggable:

```
  $('tr[index]').draggable({
    cancel: "tr.no-drag",
    opacity: 0.8,
    scroll: true,
    cursor: 'all-scroll',
    cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 },
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid",
    zIndex: 100
  });
```

My droppable:

```
$('.inside-table').droppable({
  accept: 'tr[index]',
  tolerance: "pointer",
  over: function(event, ui) {
    //highlight area to show it is droppable
  },

  out: function(event, ui) {
    // remove highlight when area is left
  },

  drop: function(event, ui) {
    //update dragged item & refresh (make sure position in table is kept)
    // only change week & user, day can be changed manually
  }
});
```

I want the clone of the draggable to stick to my cursor position, instead of miles away. Does anyone know hw to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've already found the solution (I've been looking at it for days, and of course as soon as you post the question you will solve it).

If I use `appendTo: 'body'` instead of `appendTo: 'tbody'`, the clone stays with the mouse and is not copied into the rest of the tables. The styling is then mostly gone, but that should be easier to solve/is not as big of a problem.